# linux manjaro18 MOZC辞書ツール 日本語単語の入力ができない。

Tags: linux

**環境**

仮想環境：VirtualBox 6.0.4r128413
ホストOS：macOS X 10.9.5
ゲストOS：Manjaro-xfce-18.2.0
uname:4.19.16-1-MANJARO

**やったこと**

manjaroをインストール後、日本語入力できるようにするために行ったことは以下の通りです。

1. メニューの「ソフトウエアの追加と削除」でFcitxをインストール

   - fcitx-mozc
   - fcitx-gtk2
   - fcitx-gtk3
   - fcitx-qt4
2. `~/.xprofile`を作成

```sh
export LANG="ja_JP.UTF-8"
export XMODIFIERS="@im=fcitx"
export XMODIFIER="@im=fcitx"
export GTK_IM_MODULE=fcitx
export QT_IM_MODULE=fcitx
export DefaultIMModule=fcitx
```

3. `~/.bashrc`に以下を追記

```sh
export GTK_IM_MODULE=fcitx
export XMODIFIERS=@im=fcitx
export QT_IM_MODULE=fcitx
```

通常の使用（本質問も）では問題なく「zenkakuhankaku」「ctr+スペースキー」で日本語/半角英数入力の切り替えはできている。

**質問**

ところが、日本語入力状態で「あ」のアイコンをクリックし「Mozcツール」--->「辞書ツール」とクリックすると半角英数入力に切り替わり、日本語入力にならないため日本語単語が登録できず困っています。

解決策をご存知の方がいらっしゃればご教示願いたい。

Comment: コマンドラインで辞書登録ツールを起動する場合はどうなるのでしょうか？ Manjaro-xfce では異なるかもしれませんが、Ubuntu Linux では `/usr/lib/mozc/mozc_tool --mode=dictionary_tool` とします。

Comment: コピペで「Mozc辞書ツール」は起動しましたが、やはり”よみ”のところをクリックしてzenkakuhankakuキーを押しても日本語入力には切り替わりません。

Comment: 追加でやってみたこと。Mousepad（簡易エディター）を立ち上げておき、日本語入力モードにしてターミナルで当該コマンド（？）を実行したところ、瞬時に半角英数字入力モードに切り替わります。

Answer (score 1):

https://www.mikunimaru.com/entry/anarchy の「日本語入力用のIMEをインストール」を参考にfcitx-imをインストールすることで解決しました。